# Arduino (ESP8266) not receiving all characters

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I have a file of 18164 bytes that I am trying to download from a ESP8266 (4m) but I'm only receiving part of the file (about 17000 bytes). Sometimes it will receive all but more often than not won't. The file is a minified javascript file. Smaller files of 5000 bytes work fine. If buffer size is a problem, how do I increase the buffer size for WiFiClient?

```
void setup()
{
  String line = "";
  ...

  while ((net.connected() || net.available()))
  {
    if (net.available())
    {
      char c = net.read();
      line += c;
    }
  }
  net.stop();

  Serial.println("Line:-" + line + "-");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably exhausting the available memory in your ESP8266. It doesn't have a lot to start with.

Your 4m ESP8266 has 4Mbits of flash storage (512Kbytes), but you're accumulating the file you download in RAM, which is much more scarce. The ESP8266 has 80Kbytes of RAM. Some of this RAM will already be used by the Arduino Core and network stack.

I loaded a minimal program on an ESP8266 with a connected WiFi client and saw 51Kbytes of RAM available.

You're also using `String` a lot. `String` stores the actual string itself using memory that's allocated from the free memory on the ESP8266. Each time you add a character, `String` will free its previous storage and allocate the same amount plus one byte more. The Arduino Core doesn't have particularly sophisticated memory management; this could possibly lead to heap fragmentation to a point where you just can't allocate a bigger piece of memory, and your program would fail.

You can learn about the state of free memory with these calls:

- `ESP.getFreeHeap()` - returns total amount of available memory
- `ESP.getHeapFragmentation()` - returns an indication of how badly the heap is fragmented. The bigger, the worse - over 50 is very bad.
- `ESP.getMaxFreeBlockSize()` - the biggest block you can allocate.

To verify, I'd try something like this:

```
while ((net.connected() || net.available()))
  {
    if (net.available())
    {
      char c = net.read();
      line += c;
      Serial.print("line length: ");
      Serial.println(line.length());
      Serial.print("free heap: ");
      Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
      Serial.print("heap fragmentation: ");
      Serial.println(ESP.getHeapFragmentation());
      Serial.print("max block size: ");
      Serial.println(ESP.getMaxFreeBlockSize());
    }
  }
  net.stop();
```

If the max block size gets close to or less than the length of `line`, you can no longer allocate a big enough chunk of memory to store `line + c` and your program will fail the way you described.

One thing you could try is to use the `reserve()` method on `String` after you create line. Something like:

```
String line;

line.reserve(18500);
line = "";
```

Ultimately you're much better off reading your file into a `char` array, or saving it to SPIFFS a chunk (512 would be a good size) at a time, than using `String`.